# Obtener el numero de filas de una tabla HTML con BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python-3.x, html-tabla, beautifulsoup

Estoy creando una herramienta con la cual necesito obtener la cantidad de filas de la primera columna que hay en una tabla. Específicamente de la tabla principal de [esta página](https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet) y para ello estoy usando `BeautifulSoup 4`, sin embargo no logro obtener el número correcto.

### Este es mi código

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
opener.addheaders=[
    ('User-Agent', 
    ('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) '
     'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
     'Chrome/36.0.1941.0 #Safari/537.36'))]
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

sauce          = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.tibiawiki.com.br/wiki/Amazon_Helmet')
soup           = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'html5lib')

main_table     = soup.find_all('table')[2].find_all('tr')
print(len(main_table))
```

Y el resultado que obtengo al procesar mi código es el siguiente:

```
>>> 8
```

Según mis cálculos el resultado no es el correcto ya que extraje la tabla y le hice una limpieza para poder detallarla mas fácilmente:

[image: Tabla limpia]

A mi parecer la tabla en su primera columna consta de 6 filas (o 5 contando desde 0), y ese es lo que quiero obtener, la cantidad de filas en la primera columna de dicha tabla.

**¿Alguien sabe cómo?**

Gracias de antemano.